# ADOMD.net - reading dimension and measure information on SSAS tabular cube

Tags: c#, ssas, cube, adomd.net

I am new to SSAS world. I want to read information from cube using ADOMD.net library. I need to get all the dimension and get list of measures that intersects each dimension.  What is the best approach to get this information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an AdomdCommand and call ExecuteCellSet on it. The resulting CellSet contains loads of metadata, including all the dimensions. I don't know whether it is possible to get a list of measures that intersects each dimension from that, but it might be worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

> you can view dimensions hierarchy and levels by these code sample

```
AdomdConnection conn = new AdomdConnection(ConnStr);
        conn.Open();
        List<string> cubeName = new List<string>();
        List<string> dimensions = new List<string>();
        List<string> hierarchyList = new List<string>();
        List<string> levels = new List<string>();
        foreach (CubeDef cube in conn.Cubes)
        {
            cubeName.Add(cube.Name.ToString());

            foreach (Dimension dimension in cube.Dimensions) 
            {
                dimensions.Add(dimension.Name.ToString());
                foreach (Hierarchy hierarchy in dimension.Hierarchies) 
                 {
                    hierarchyList.Add(hierarchy.Name.ToString());

                    foreach (Level level in hierarchy.Levels) 
                    {
                        levels.Add(level.Name.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
      var data = new { cubeName,dimensions,hierarchyList,levels  };    

     return data
```